# I am trying to overwrite sticky keys(sethc.exe) with cmd.exe but when running the script it cant find files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to overwrite two files with each other but it gives me a message that it cant find the files specified.

```
@echo off
set /p Drive=Enter local hard drive letter: 
if "%Drive%"=="" goto :eof
xcopy Drive:\windows\system32\sethc.exe Drive:
xcopy Drive:\windows\system32\cmd.exe Drive:\windows\system32\sethc.exe
```

Comment: This is incredibly dangerous. If you were to press shift 5 times at the login screen then you would get a command prompt as the system account!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you files are in the same path as your batch file is, for example:

```
@echo off
start minecraft.exe
```

In this example, obviously it starts minecraft, but in the format it currently is, it would require minecraft to be located on your desktop if your batch file is on your desktop, if minecraft.exe is in a folder named "Folder1" then you would type:

```
@echo off
Start "C:\Users\<your name>\Desktop\Folder1\minecraft.exe"
```

In order for this to work, your batch file will also need to be located in Folder1 as well. Obviously, instead of minecraft.exe, you would use the files that you are using.

As long as your batch file is in the same path as your files then it should work. I hope the example I used helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%drive%` where you should use `drive`

and using `drive` where you should use `%drive%`